# Home page vertical Nav bar not displaying all the categories

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have a problem with my site that I'm developing. I have bought a template, and unfortunately, the vertical navbar is not expanding. I have more than the categories displayed in the navbar, but the +Category button is not working, and I can see that chrome says void(0); at the bottom of the page. I tried contacting the template developer, but no luck, and I have no idea how to diagnose this issue. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

In case you wanted to visit the website you can check it out [here](https://entregaste.com/portuguese/).

[image: nav bar not expanding]

Comment: In manage category, check if "Include in Menu" option is enable on the categories that are not showing in menu

Comment: Enabling the button displays the items in both vertical and horizontal menu and still the button is non responsive. It just added those categories to the top of the button.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix problem by limiting the visible categories and that somehow made the button work.

The limit value was set on 10 which for some reason it was breaking the button. Changing it to anything less that fixed the issue.

[image]

Comment: Add the solution here

Comment: Added. Sorry I forgot to add the photo